# Is it feasible to improve performance of SQL server with caching?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, redis

What is the most common and easy to implement solution to improve speed for SQL Server 2008R2 database & .Net 3.5 application.

We have an application with the following attributes:
- small number of simultaneous clients (~200 at MOST).
- complex math operations on SQL server side
- we are imitating something to oracle's [row-level security](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/restricting_access.htm) (Thus using tvf's and storedprocs instead of directly querying tables)
-The main problem is that users perform high amount of updates/inserts/deletes/calculations, and they freak out because they need to wait for pages to reload while those actions are done.

The questions I need clarification on are as follows:

1. What is faster: returning whole dataset from sql server and performing math functions on C# side, or performing calculation functions on sql side (thus, not returning extra columns). Or is it only hardware dependant?
2. Will caching improve performance (For example if we add redis cache). Or caching solutions only feasible for large number of clients?
3. Is it a bad practice to pre-calculate some of the data and store somewhere in the database (so, when user will request, it will already be calculated). Or this is what caching suppose to do? If this is not a bad practice, how do you configure SQL server to do calculations when there are available resources?
4. How caching can improve performance if it still needs to go to the database and see if any records were updated?

general suggestions and comments are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's separate the answer to two parts, performance of your query execution and caching to improve that performance. 
I believe you should start with addressing the load on your SQL server and try to optimize process running on it to the maximum, this should resolve most of the need to implement any caching.

From your question it appears that you have a system that is used for both transactional processing and also for aggregations/calculations, this will often result in conflicts when these two tasks lock each other resources. A long query performing math operations may lock/hold an object required by the UI. 
Optimizing these systems to work side-by-side and improving the query efficiency is the key for having increased performance.

To start, I'll use your questions. What is faster? depends on the actual aggregation you are performing, if you're dealing with a set operations, i.e. SUM/AVG of a column, keep it in SQL, on the other hand if you find yourself having a cursor in the procedure, move it to C#. Cursors will kill your performance! 
You asked if it's bad-practice to aggregate data aside and later query that repository, this is the best practice :). You'll end up with having one database catering the transactional, high-paced clients and another database storing the aggregated info, this will be quickly and easily available for your other needs. Taking it to the next step will result with you having a data warehouse, so this is definitely where you want to be heading when you have a lot information and calculations.

Lastly, caching, this is tricky and really depends on the specific nature of your needs, I'd say take the above approach, spend the time in improving the processes and I expect the end result will make caching redundant.

One of your best friends for the task is SQL Profiler, run a trace on stmt:completed to see what are the highest duration/io/cpu and pick on them first.

Good luck!

Comment: Definitely agree about SQL Profiler